# If I want the data of simulate zone in certain frame, what should I do?

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

For example, simulating a live curve, I have it instance fruit midway, or generate points that can create new forks.

I don't want to use random booleans to make it, it feels a bit uncontrollable.

I saw a blogger controlling how many frames were simulated by adding simulation input, but it seems that this only exists in the alpha version of 3.5, while the 3.6 and 4.0 versions seem to not work. Forcing connections may even cause crashes.

[image]

Reprint link: https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1fM4y187ZA/?spm_id_from=333.788&vd_source=0b4460c3eccd18dbedd51dc9d35ed8e6

Comment: ...It might help to answer your question if your screenshot contained nodes that are displayed in English.